# Selecting all elements up until reaching a specific one

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

There is a container div which has other divs inside of it, these child divs contain text with some links in them. I'm trying to select all the anchor tags that are inside of this container div **except** for those that come **after** a child div which has a specific class to it.

```
<div id="the_container">

 <div>
  some text <a href="...">link</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  some text <a href="...">link</a>
 </div>
 ... more regular divs below...

 <div class="NOT_a_regular_child">
  this is not text
 </div>

 <div>
  some text <a href="...">link</a>
 </div>
 ... more divs come below...

</div>
```

So, from the HTML above I'd like to select only the links before the div which class is "NOT_a_regular_child".

I googled it but it seems like there isn't a selector for getting elements before another (?)

I believe I could select all the child divs then loop through them and dump their links to an array until I reach that specific one but isn't there a way to do this using css selectors only?

I cannot change the structure of the HTML because I'm just writing a google chrome extension to work on a existing web site.

Comment: jQuery nextUntil:

dir: function( elem, dir, until ) {
  var matched = [],
   cur = elem[ dir ];

  while ( cur && cur.nodeType !== 9 && (until === undefined || cur.nodeType !== 1 || !jQuery( cur ).is( until )) ) {
   if ( cur.nodeType === 1 ) {
    matched.push( cur );
   }
   cur = cur[dir];
  }
  return matched;
 },

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pure CSS

Nothing complex about setting up a pure css way to target those using the general sibling selector `~`.

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3XhB/2/)** for the below code performance.

```
.the_container a {
    color: blue; 
    /* base link color and styling for container 
       this will be applied to all links above the class
    */
}

/* second selector is optional only if you need to 
handle links in that specially classed container */

.the_container > div.NOT_a_regular_child ~ div a,
.the_container > div.NOT_a_regular_child a /* <-- optional */
{
    color: red;
    /* base link color and styling for container 
       this will be applied to all links above the class
    */
}
```

Comment: The question seems to be about using selectors to match the given elements with JavaScript, which as I said in my deleted answer cannot be done. I'm not sure if your answer fits right with the question at hand, but when using CSS the overriding technique here definitely comes in very handy.

Comment: Alright, that's cool! I didn't know about that selector. Thanks

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah I am selecting the links in js in order to aply some style to them, but I think I can append another style element to the page and do it like that right?

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if all that was needed was styling. I glossed over part of the question, and somehow thought that an Array of hrefs was needed. ...I also could have sworn that I saw jQuery in the question. So my answer was misplaced anyway.

Comment: @Delta: In that case, yes you should be able to. My initial impression was that you were trying to match the elements for DOM scripting rather than applying styles.

Comment: @amnotiam oh that's because I said "dump the links to an array" but I actually meant the elements not their href value, sorry for the confusion. I just had to adapt your answer a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function get_p_class(){
var childDivs = document.getElementById('the_container').getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var childDiv = 0;  childDiv < childDivs.length; childDiv++){
    if(childDivs[childDiv].className=="NOT_a_regular_child"){
        //code...
        childDivs[childDiv].className="this_new_class";
        //some other change 
        //or 
        //change the if statement to match what every you would like to do.
    }
 }
}

window.onload = function() {
        get_p_class();
    }
```